# In EhCache3 does a persistent cache mean that data always has to be written to the disk cache

Tags: java, ehcache, ehcache-3

With Ehcache 3 if I have a persistent cache does that mean that everything will be written to the disk cache even if the heap/offheap caches are full or not ?

i.e I have this

```
PersistentCacheManager cacheManager = CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder()
                .with(CacheManagerBuilder.persistence(new File(Platform.getPlatformDatabaseFolder(), RELEASE_CACHE)))
                .withCache(RELEASE_CACHE,
                        CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(
                                String.class,
                                String.class,
                                ResourcePoolsBuilder.newResourcePoolsBuilder()
                                        .heap(100, EntryUnit.ENTRIES)
                                        .offheap(10, MemoryUnit.MB)
                                        .disk(20, MemoryUnit.MB, true)))
                .build();
```

So I am expirmenting with this but I have specified a disk cache because usually memory cache will not be sufficient, and I have specified it to be persistent because if data is written to the disk it may well be useful for subsequent runs of the application.

However, sometimes the application may be used in such a way that the heap/offheap is not fully used, therefore I do not want the application to be wasting time writing data to disk just because I have marked it as persistent. After all the reason I am using a cache is to improve performance.

Comment: the os will flush it to disk, the app won't waste time.

Comment: but sometimes my app runs on a slow 1 cpu machines, so if the os has to do extra stuff that will slow things down, so to clarify it will write all to disk ?

Comment: i am not an expert on this, but maybe with just 1 cpu, the high I/O load writing to disk blocks your thread for a long time. It may be difficult to adress..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [documented](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.7/tiering.html#multi-tier-sequence-flow), whenever you have multiple tiers in Ehcache, the lowest tier (disk in your case) always see the `put` to the cache, while higher tiers are simply invalidated (offheap and heap in your case). On a `get` the value is pulled into the highest tier (heap in your case) for fast subsequent access. If that results in eviction from heap, then the evicted value is pushed down to offheap and, in cascade, that could cause an eviction from offheap to disk.

Note that the above system is done so that performance remains predictable instead of dropping suddenly when a tier gets full.

So there is a cost to have multiple tiers in Ehcache. Depending on your use case, it might be better to have less tiering options activated. As always with caching: measure and adapt.

Comment: okay well I always need the lowest tier because the idea is to improve performance whilst controlling memory usage so if I didnt have disk persistence then I could only store limited number of items. But if I didnt have heap persistence then would always be reading cache form disk so would be to slow. I was previously using Hibernate but since the objects dont change I wanted to get away from the overhead of full database management including locking mechanisms.

Comment: But maybe there is little point in having both heap and nonheap